# Trying to extract data from curly braces but not working

Tags: vba, excel

I need to sync up the values in the curly braces {} found in column C and put them against the user id in column F as seen below.

E.g. on the Emails sheet

[image]

becomes this on a new sheet

[image]

```
Sub CopyConditional()
Dim wshS As Worksheet
Dim WhichName As String

Set wshS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Emails")
WhichName = "NewSheet"

Const NameCol = "C"
Const FirstRow = 1

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SrcRow As Long
Dim TrgRow As Long
Dim wshT As Worksheet
Dim cpt As String
Dim user As String
Dim computers() As String
Dim computer As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wshT = Worksheets(WhichName)
If wshT Is Nothing Then
    Set wshT = Worksheets.Add(After:=wshS)
    wshT.Name = WhichName
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If wshT.Cells(1, NameCol).value = "" Then
    TrgRow = 1
Else
    TrgRow = wshT.Cells(wshT.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If

LastRow = wshS.Cells(wshS.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
    cpt = wshS.Range("C" & SrcRow).value
    user = wshS.Range("F" & SrcRow).value

    If InStr(cpt, ":") Then
        cpt = Mid(cpt, InStr(1, cpt, ":") + 1, Len(cpt))
    End If

    If InStr(cpt, ";") Then
        computers = Split(cpt, ";")
        For i = 0 To UBound(computers)
            If computers(i) <> "" Then
                wshT.Range("A" & TrgRow).value = user
                wshT.Range("B" & TrgRow).value = Mid(Left(computers(i), Len(computers(i)) - 1), 2)
                TrgRow = TrgRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    Else
        computer = cpt
        If computer <> "" Then
            wshT.Range("A" & TrgRow).value = user
            wshT.Range("B" & TrgRow).value = Mid(Left(computer, Len(computer) - 1), 2)
            TrgRow = TrgRow + 1
        End If
    End If

Next SrcRow

End Sub
```

**I managed to resolve it with the above code but there are 3 niggling issues:**

1) The first curly brace is always copied, how do I omit this so something like `{Computer1` looks like `Computer 1`

[image]

2) Where there are two computers in a row, then the output looks something like this:

[image]

when it should really be split into two different rows i.e.

```
User 1 | Computer 1
User 1 | Computer 2
```

3) If there is text after the last curly brace with text in it e.g. `{Computer1};{Computer2};Request submitted` then that text is added as a new row, I don't want this, I want it to be omitted e.g.

[image]

should just be:

```
User 1 | Computer 1
User 1 | Computer 2
```

How do I go about rectifying these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Collapse()
    Dim uRng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim comps As Variant, comp As Variant, r As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim d As Dictionary '~~> Early bind, for Late bind use commented line
    'Dim d As Object
    Dim a As String

    With Sheet1 '~~> Sheet that contains your data
        Set uRng = .Range("F1", .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With d
        For Each cel In uRng
            a = Replace(cel.Offset(0, -3), "{", "}")
            comps = Split(a, "}")
            Debug.Print UBound(comps)
            For Each comp In comps
                If InStr(comp, "Computer") <> 0 _
                And Len(Trim(comp)) <= 10 Then '~~> I assumed max Comp# is 99
                    If Not .Exists(cel) Then
                        .Add cel, comp
                    Else
                        If IsArray(.Item(cel)) Then
                            r = .Item(cel)
                            ReDim Preserve r(UBound(r) + 1)
                            r(UBound(r)) = comp
                            .Item(cel) = r
                        Else
                            r = Array(.Item(cel), comp)
                            .Item(cel) = r
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

    For Each v In d.Keys
        With Sheet2 '~~> sheet you want to write your data to
            If IsArray(d.Item(v)) Then
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
                    .Resize(UBound(d.Item(v)) + 1) = v
                .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
                    .Resize(UBound(d.Item(v)) + 1) = Application.Transpose(d.Item(v))
            Else
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = v
                .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = d.Item(v)
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Set d = Nothing

End Sub
```

Above code uses *Replace and Split Function*  to pass your string to array.

```
a = Replace(cel.Offset(0, -3), "{", "}") '~~> standardize delimiter
comps = Split(a, "}") '~~> split using standard delimiter
```

Then information are passed to dictionary object using User as key and computers as items.
We filter the items passed to dictionary using *Instr and Len Function*

```
If InStr(comp, "Computer") <> 0 _
And Len(Trim(comp)) <= 10 Then
```

As I've commented, I assumed your max computer number is 99.
Else change 10 to whatever length you need to check.
Finally we return the dictionary information to the target worksheet.
**Note:** You need to add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime if you prefer early bind

**Result:** I tried it on a small sample data patterned on how I see it in you SS.

So assuming you have this data in Sheet1:
[image]

Will output data in Sheet2 like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm getting a `user-defined type not defined` error message at `Dim d As Dictionary`

Comment: See my note. Or you can use the commented line instead `Dim d As Object`.

Comment: It works now but there is no output on sheet2 - see code at http://pastebin.com/Bn5CYE6b

Comment: @methuselah Sheet1 and Sheet2 are worksheet codenames. Make sure you're checking the correct sheets.

Comment: @methuselah btw, here's my test file which I used during testing http://wikisend.com/download/397838

Comment: I just double clicked one of the cells and this is what the data looks like http://imgur.com/e8hdd7O, I think this is why the code wasn't working - I've added it here http://ge.tt/7GfAGlj1/v/0?c

Answer (score 1):

1) Use the Mid function to drop the first character:

```
str = "{Computer1"
str = Mid(str,2)
```

now str = "Computer1"

2) You can use the Split function to separate these out and combine with the Mid function above

```
str = "{Computer1}{Computer2}"
splt = Split(str,"}")
for a = 0 to Ubound(splt)
     result = Mid(splt(a),2)
next a
```

3) Add a conditional statement to the above loop

```
str = "{Computer1}{Computer2}"
splt = Split(str,"}")
for a = 0 to Ubound(splt)
     if Left(splt(a),1) = "{" then result = Mid(splt(a),2)
next a
```

Use this loop and send each result to the desired cell (in the for-next loop) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Matthew - how would I incorporate this into my code?

Comment: Run it right before you put the string in a cell, replacing str with the string variable you are using (I was just using it to demonstrate). I'm not on my computer, otherwise I'd incorporate it for you.

Comment: @methuselah - do you want splt(a,.. instead of splt(0,.. ?

Answer (score 1):

I use a custom parse function for this type of operation:

```
Sub CopyConditional()
  ' some detail left out
  Dim iRow&, Usern$, Computer$, Computers$
  For iRow = ' firstrow To lastrow
    Usern = Sheets("Emails").Cells(iRow, "F")
    Computers = Sheets("Emails").Cells(iRow, "C")
    Do
      Computer = zParse(Computers) ' gets one computer
      If Computer = "" Then Exit Do
      ' Store Computer and Usern
    Loop
  Next iRow
End Sub

Function zParse$(Haystack$) ' find all {..}
  Static iPosL& '
  Dim iPosR&
  If iPosL = 0 Then iPosL = 1
  iPosL = InStr(iPosL, Haystack, "{") ' Left
  If iPosL = 0 Then Exit Function ' no more
  iPosR = InStr(iPosL, Haystack, "}") ' Right
  If iPosR = 0 Then MsgBox "No matching }": Stop
  zParse = Mid$(Haystack, iPosL + 1, iPosR - iPosL - 1)
  iPosL = iPosR
End Function
```