# Script does not produce output on second sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a script that needs to produce an output on a new sheet in the same workbook (not a directly referenced sheet as the code below insinuates), but I've currently ran into an issue where the content from one sheet is not being copied to another. It runs but does nothing at all. How can I resolve this?

```
Sub Collapse()
Dim uRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim comps As Variant, comp As Variant, r As Variant, v As Variant
'Dim d As Dictionary '~~> Early bind, for Late bind use commented line
Dim d As Object
Dim a As String

Dim Emails As Worksheet
Set Emails = Sheets("Emails")

With Emails '~~> Sheet that contains your data
    Set uRng = .Range("F1", .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With d
    For Each cel In uRng
        a = Replace(cel.Offset(0, -3), "{", "}")
        comps = Split(a, "}")
        Debug.Print UBound(comps)
        For Each comp In comps
            If InStr(comp, "Computer") <> 0 _
            And Len(Trim(comp)) <= 10 Then '~~> I assumed max Comp# is 99
                If Not .Exists(cel) Then
                    .Add cel, comp
                Else
                    If IsArray(.Item(cel)) Then
                        r = .Item(cel)
                        ReDim Preserve r(UBound(r) + 1)
                        r(UBound(r)) = comp
                        .Item(cel) = r
                    Else
                        r = Array(.Item(cel), comp)
                        .Item(cel) = r
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With

For Each v In d.Keys
    With Sheet2 '~~> sheet you want to write your data to
        If IsArray(d.Item(v)) Then
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
                .Resize(UBound(d.Item(v)) + 1) = v
            .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) _
                .Resize(UBound(d.Item(v)) + 1) = Application.Transpose(d.Item(v))
        Else
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = v
            .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = d.Item(v)
        End If
    End With
Next
Set d = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use breakpoints and watches to test which part of the code works. I would look especially if "d" contains anything

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the `Exists` check. [I had a similar issue at some point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742778/strange-behavior-of-range-when-used-as-key-in-dictionary), it is safer to use `Range.Value` instead of `Range` as key in a dictionary. The accepted response in the link might help.

Comment: Hi. Try being explicit in `cel` by using `cel.Value`. Although this works at my end explicit or not. Also, @loannis is right so might as well check the solution that worked for him. You can also check my comment [Trying to extract data from curly braces but not workingTrying to extract data from curly braces but not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070886/trying-to-extract-data-from-curly-braces-but-not-working/24073626#24073626) in this thread.

Comment: I've uploaded it here if anyone is interested - http://ge.tt/7GfAGlj1/v/0?c